# How to save the audio file with AudioUnits in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, avfoundation

I am trying to do TimeStretching of Audio files with Audiounits.

I am using this code. http://pastebin.com/DWMTw4n9

Here's the sample project i'm using : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12216224/buglets/TimeSliderDemo-Buglet.zip

How to save the audio file with AudioUnits in ios?

What have I tried:

Trying to save the audio through

```
OSStatus MyAURenderCallback(void *inRefCon,
                        AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *actionFlags,
                        const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                        UInt32 inBusNumber,
                        UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                        AudioBufferList *ioData) {

AudioUnit mixerUnit = (AudioUnit)inRefCon;

AudioUnitRender(mixerUnit,
                actionFlags,
                inTimeStamp,
                0,
                inNumberFrames,
                ioData);

//Store the Audio units in a File
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *outputURL = paths[0];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager createDirectoryAtPath:outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
outputURL = [outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"outputRamp.aif"];

ExtAudioFileWriteAsync((__bridge ExtAudioFileRef)(outputURL),
                       inNumberFrames,
                       ioData);

return noErr;
}


AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct = {0};
callbackStruct.inputProc = MyAURenderCallback;
//    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = mixerUnit;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)self;

AudioUnitSetProperty(self.effectUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                     0,
                     &callbackStruct,
                     sizeof(callbackStruct));
```

But the Call back is never called. Is it the correct way to save the Audiounits in a file ?

Answer (score 1):

you should set input callback function for a node `

```
AURenderCallbackStruct inputCallbackStruct;
inputCallbackStruct.inputProc = &MyAURenderCallback;
inputCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);


OSStatus result = noErr;


// Attach the render callback function to remoteIO's input on bus 0
result = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (
                                      self.auGraph,
                                      ioNode,
                                      0,
                                      &inputCallbackStruct
                                      );


CheckError(result, "AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback");
```

see the sample project [Audio Mixer](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/samplecode/MixerHost/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) and [How to add a Render Callback to RemoteIO after a Mixer in iOS](http://tomplaskon.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/how-to-add-a-render-callback-to-remoteio-after-a-mixer-in-ios/)

you should create `ExtAudioFileRef recordingfileref`

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription dstFormat;
dstFormat.mSampleRate=44100.0;
dstFormat.mFormatID=kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
dstFormat.mFormatFlags=kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian|kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger|kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;

dstFormat.mBytesPerPacket=4;
dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame=4;
dstFormat.mFramesPerPacket=1;
dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame=2;
dstFormat.mBitsPerChannel=16;
dstFormat.mReserved=0;

// create the capture file
status=  ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(_outputURL), kAudioFileWAVEType, &dstFormat, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &_recordingfileref);
//CheckError( status ,"couldnt create audio file");
// set the capture file's client format to be the canonical format from the queue




status=ExtAudioFileSetProperty(self.recordingfileref, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription), &StreamFormat);
```

and then you can write iodata

```
ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(recordingfileref,
                   inNumberFrames,
                   ioData);
```

when you are finished

```
OSStatus status = ExtAudioFileDispose(_recordingfileref);

printf("OSStatus(ExtAudioFileDispose): %ld\n", status);
```

Comment: @ sheraza Thanks for your reply. I have followed the steps provided.. But in ExtAudioFileWriteAsync writing the audio file, i'm getting the error response (-50). Any idea to resolve this issue ?